# What is ".lifecycle-trojan" in my AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-security, trojan

I am using the `implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'` in my project.

When I build the release or debug apk and open AndroidManifest.xml from within the apk,

I see this line.

```
<provider android:authorities="com.myapp.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="90" android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"/>
<provider android:authorities="com.myapp.testapp.lifecycle-trojan" android:exported="false" android:multiprocess="true" android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer"/>
```

Should I be worried?

I also see this in the build->intermediates->instant_app_manifest_debug->AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I cannot find any information about lifecycle-trojan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be worried?

No you shouldn't. It's used by the `ProcessLifecycleOwner`, and it is not a malware.

**Further proofs**

As you can see from the `aosp-mirror`, the file get merged from [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/ba069d50913c3fb250bb60ec310439db36895337/lifecycle/extensions/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), and after few months from the release they have changed the file to [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/557a60cba37e5c335eb35f07cb9b84c5d4933dc8/lifecycle/process/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) version.

**Solution**

Migrating to `androidx` should solve it. Now they have renamed the name from `lifecycle-trojan` to `lifecycle-process`.

You can find more information [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/a0wxm1/lifecycletrojan/)